# Get data from model in django with ajax

Tags: html, django, ajax

I have a django website which needs interaction through ajax. One of my pages includes a checkbox and I would like the data displayed on the client to depend on the state of my checkbox.

Here is my view.py :

```
...
def sales_view(request):
dataModel = DataModel()

return state_view(request, dataModel.m_bp.m_sales.m_name, sales_html)
...
```

And my template sales_html.py (not a .html file as I use airium :

```
from airium import Airium
from contextlib import contextmanager
from ..DataModel import DataModel


@contextmanager
def sales_html(a: Airium, dataModel: DataModel):
    # Page Heading
    with a.div(klass="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4"):
        a.h1(klass="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800", _t=dataModel.m_bp.m_sales.m_name)
        a.input(type = "checkbox", id = "yearMonthToggle", onclick = "myFunction()")
        a.script(src = "{% static 'src/js/test.js' %}", type = "text/javascript")

    # Get data from the model.
    myData = dataModel.getMyData()
    ...

# Display the main ItemsGroups.
a.div(klass="yearMonthContainer")
   ...code that will depend on user interactions...
```

Note that I use airium rather than direct html + dtl to handle model dependent display (as I find it easier to handle all the data logic but this does not change much for my question.

And for the javascript I have found this below, but I cannot find an easy way to call a django view from my script, the only think whih I have found and which is easy is loading a static html, but then I cannot access my model in django and write model dependent data. What I have is

```
const xhr_checked   = new XMLHttpRequest();

var checkBox  = document.getElementById("yearMonthToggle");
var container = document.getElementById("yearMonthContainer");

xhr_checked.onload = function myFunction()
{
    if (checkBox.checked == true)
    {
        container.innerHTML = xhr_checked.responseText;
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }
}

xhr_checked.open('get', 'sales_html_yearly.html')
xhr_checked.send()
```

This works well for pure html but as it does not go through django then I cannot display data from my model. Any idea how I shall do this?